# Cannot get data from MS SQL database using ColdFusion

Tags: sql, database, coldfusion

I'm using ColdFusion and trying to get data from a MS SQL database. The problem is there should be only one line with details. At the same time if I'm trying to login as user or admin it works fine. The syntax is basically the same as for admin login. Maybe I've missed something? Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>


<cfquery name='Query' datasource='MyDSN'>
<cfset "id" = #Form.user#/>
SELECT UserID, FName, SName, Phone, Address FROM users WHERE UserID = <cfqueryparam   value="#FORM.user#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>


</head>
<body>

 <cfif #Query.recordCount# EQ 1>


<TABLE height="30px" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="3">
<TR BGCOLOR="888888" >
<TH>User ID         </TH> 
<TH>Name    </TH>
<TH>Surname </TH> 
<TH>Phone   </TH>
<TH>Address </TH> 
</TR>
<TD><cfoutput> #Query.UserID# </cfoutput></TD>
<TD><cfoutput> # Query.FName# </cfoutput></TD>
<TD><cfoutput> # Query.SName# </cfoutput></TD>
<TD><cfoutput> # Query.Phone# </cfoutput></TD>
<TD><cfoutput> # Query.Address# </cfoutput></TD></TR>

<cfelse>
<cfoutput> No such user...</cfoutput>
</cfif>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Is there always a form posted with a "user" text input, or can this page be requested directly? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Form.user has a variable in it. The script displays variable when query returns nothing from database.. So it's there

Comment: If you run the query outside coldfusion, do you get a record?  Also, what is the datatype of userid?

Comment: datatype is nvarchar. I tried tu run that page with hardcoded UserID  bu its returning  error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original query and your error message are not from the same code. Your error message shows you're listing your column names in the FROM statement. This is the correct syntax.

```
<cfquery name='Query' datasource='MyDSN'>
SELECT UserID, FName, SName, Phone, Address 
FROM users
WHERE UserID = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(FORM.user)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery
```

From Leigh's chat - make sure you're not adding in leading/trailing zeroes when using `cfqueryparam`.

Also, in your cfif statement, `#` are not needed.

```
<cfif Query.recordCount EQ 1>
```

To fix the issue with your output not working

```
<cfif Query.recordCount EQ 1>
  <cfoutput>
    <TABLE height="30px" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="3">
    <TR BGCOLOR="888888" >
      <TH>User ID</TH> 
      <TH>Name</TH>
      <TH>Surname</TH> 
      <TH>Phone</TH>
      <TH>Address</TH> 
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>#Query.UserID#</TD>
      <TD>#Query.FName#</TD>
      <TD>#Query.SName#</TD>
      <TD>#Query.Phone#</TD>
      <TD>#Query.Address#</TD>
    </TR>
  </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput> #Form.user#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: +1 - I deleted my answer Matt since we came to the exact same conclusion. Great minds...

Comment: yes it is from different.. There's a note on the top-it's from query that I tried to run on a separate page

Comment: Yes  I fixed the query Sorry I'm a noob ))) now it prints out data like that :  "&Query.Address&"

Comment: I'm back..... When I replace hardcoded id it gives out error:  Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The multi-part identifier "mail@email.com" could not be bound.

Comment: @Dims - Did you enclose the variable in quotes, or better yet use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) with the correct type. ie `WHERE UserID = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.user#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">` ?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the *exact* cfquery causing the "could not be bound..." error?

Comment: @Dims - Sorry, but that query would *not* cause the "...`multi-part identifier "mail@email.com" could not be bound.`". So that cannot be the same query .. (As an aside, the `cfset` should be moved outside the query tags)

Comment: It is.... I just copied the whole page.. And I also took cfif out as you said.. No difference

Comment: When UserID is hardcoded it works like charm... Is it something to do with Form.user variable or its format...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29930/discussion-between-leigh-and-dims)

Comment: @Dims - The problem is white space in your `form` code. See my last comment in the chat.

Comment: Thank you thank yo thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It DOES return details now!!!!! God bless You Leigh!!!!!! :-)))))))  Thanks EVERY one!!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your problem. I assume the query doesn't return the proper results. Is your list of columnnames exactly what the asterisk `*` gives back?  (As a sidenote, one should never use asterisk in a `select`.)

Also make sure that the data type of:

> `<cfqueryparam value= "#Form.user#">`

matches the data type of the `UserID` column.

Comment: The problem is it seem to return nothing from database... recordcount  is not GT than 0... Because second condition if cfif  fires..And it's showing actual id. So I assume the proper id is there. I tried to use only #Form.user# in query (without cfqueryparam value=..) but still no results.. And also i tried to specify columns to return in query - same... It my first wee with Coldfusion so I'm a noob )))

Comment: Sounds like a data problem - have you ran the query directly, hardcoding a value for the UserID?